# Run gcc -gcodeview

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I want to run gcc on Windows + MSYS2|UCRT64 with the [-gcodeview flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html), to generate pdb files. Those are required, to generate stacktraces including line numbers in source files.

But gcc/g++ always reports, that the debug level is unrecognized: `g++: error: unrecognized debug output level ‘codeview’`

Do I have to compile and configure gcc with a specific flag to support CodeView?

Comment: Consider using Clang, which already supports the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the GCC documentation you linked to is for the *development* branch 14.0. The current *release*, 13.1.0, [doesn't include `-gcodeview` in its debug options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html). So it's something new added for 14.

My MSYS2/mingw64 installation is using gcc 13.1.0; I assume the ucrt64 version is too.

So, basically, to generate codeview debug information, you either need to install a development version of gcc (Possibly having to build it from source) and hope it's in a usable state, or wait for 14.1 to be released and adopted.